# can it be done with 2D engine or is it real 3D?

Tags: isometric, andengine, tilemap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I sort images in an isometric game so that they appear in the correct order?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8151/how-should-i-sort-images-in-an-isometric-game-so-that-they-appear-in-the-correct)
>   [My isometric game looks flat; how can I improve this?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18982/my-isometric-game-looks-flat-how-can-i-improve-this)

I'm working with andengine on a tiled map, at the moment I have only something like this 
[image]

However I want to manage/introduce "heigth" like the folowing image.

Can I do this or have I do change my engine, I want now something like this :

Do you have some example/tuto explaining how to manage a "3D" tiled map?

[image]

Comment: Given that 1001 isometric titles from the 8 and 16-bit eras managed it just fine without 3D chips, I think the answer is an obvious yes. If you want a useful answer, then I suggest you rephrase your question to be "How do I determine draw order for isometric 2D including height?"

Comment: Then close the question as a duplicate. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18982/my-isometric-game-looks-flat-how-can-i-improve-this?rq=1 and http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8151/how-should-i-sort-images-in-an-isometric-game-so-that-they-appear-in-the-correct

Comment: Height in isometric transforms can be done by adding a Y offset when drawing your tiles and objects. The drawing order between tiles remains the same, but you need to draw items on the same tile coordinate from the bottom up.